# How to programmatically set a value to md-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-select

Im following this [doc](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) for `md-select` initial value setting. But i would like to set the value of `md-select` programmatically through buttons.

Here is what ive'd done so far [DEMO](http://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/EZVKQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`md-select` is expecting object value to be there in `selectedUser`, where as `filter` does return array of filtered object. You should be assigning 1st element of filtered array by doing `[0]` of filtered result.

```
$scope.selectedUser = $scope.users.filter(function(user) {
     return user.id == id;
})[0];
```

[**Forked Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygYOGz)

Comment: Never thought it was simple as that